# Django is taking a long time to load

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

For some reason, Django just started taking a really long time to load.

When running `python manage.py runserver`it takes about 30 seconds for the server to run. But everything looks normal.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader 
Performing system checks... 

System check identified no issues (0 silenced). 
March 12, 2020 - 19:59:26 
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'navio.settings' 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

And after, every page takes about 22 seconds to load.

Any clue about what is happening? The only thing I did before this happened was creating and then deleting a file called `templatetags.py`.

Comment: Poor man's debugging tip: try running the server and halting it during startup with `CTRL-C` a few times. The resulting stack traces may provide some insight as to where things are being slowed down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, restarting the computer fixed it.

Comment: yeah, definitely fixed!

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can install [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to check CPU/DB time and find a long running query, if that's a problem.
Another option is to profile django app. Here are [some](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango) [articles](https://www.gun.io/blog/fast-as-fuck-django-part-1-using-a-profiler) you may want to read.

If this is production app, you can check for [Newrelic](https://newrelic.com) for a trial period.

Possible reasons are:

- long running queries
- requests to external servises, that respond with noticible delay (or fail after timeout)
- insufficient system resourses
- many other things

Comment: With django-debug-toolbar what I get is: 23160.85ms total time, 12 SQL queries, in 30.61ms, 15 static files and 7 receivers from 12 signals.

Comment: definitely not a DB problem. Now try to check network requests - use developers console in your browser -> network tab -> fully reload page and see if there are anything that take too much time to load

Comment: The favicon is taking 317ms to load. The rest of the static files take about 20ms.

Comment: Ok, nothing obvious - it's time for profiling your app. Check articles I left to start with.

Comment: I am using python 3, so it's not letting me install `hotshot`

Comment: Ok, then how about [this](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/django-web-profiler)?

Comment: I will try it. But also, `pip install` is taking a really long time too.

Comment: And what about any other python scripts? Maybe because of some reasons you run out of resourses or your storage device feeling really bad?

Answer (score 0):

Something to ask is are doing any processing of your assets?
I was very stupidly running `npx` instead of `npm` when in debug mode to install a freshly minified version. `npx` runs a `npm` package without installing it, which means everytime before it runs, it downloads the package, run the commands, then cleans up after itself... all in about 3seconds per command.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone googles this, make sure that any of the classes you have don't have an intensive function call in `__init__`.

I also recommend using django debug toolbar.

https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I faced a similar issue, where I had a class in a helper function, this class had deep learning models in the init, hence it took a longer time to initialize. After just removing that helper python file from the import of views, the loading time was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into a very similar problem, Django server was taking too long to run any command (makemigrations, migrate, runserver, etc). This was caused because i deleted the I suggest that you check that the **pycache** folder exists.